# navigator.pop() in callback function form redux action

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I am implementing a small app where I need to insert some data in firebase, then pop the screen from the stack after the data insert is completed.

I am now calling the action, and passing a callback function to be executed after data is inserted, my code below:

**EmployeeCreate.js**

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { name, phone, shift, navigator } = this.props;
    this.props.employeeCreate({ name, phone, shift: shift || 'Monday' }, () => {
        console.log('REDIRECT FUNCTION HERE');
        navigator.pop({
        animated: true, // does the pop have transition animation or does it happen immediately (optional)
        animationType: 'fade', // 'fade' (for both) / 'slide-horizontal' (for android) does the pop have different transition animation (optional)
        });
    });
}
```

**EmployeeActions.js**

```
export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }, callbackFunction) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return () => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .push({ name, phone, shift })
    .then(callbackFunction);
    //type: EMPLOYEE_CREATE
  };
};
```

The action doesn't go through a reducer now, and the app seems to work fine. I am just wondering if I am doing it correctly, or if there is a better way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `employeeCreate` function seems like an Async Action, the async action likes below:

```
function testAsync(arg1, arg2) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    // dispatch(...)
    fetch(...)
    .then(result => {
      // dispatch(...)
    })
  }
}
```

You just didn't call `dispatch` in `employeeCreate`.

Comment: Thanks @Jacky. Actually my question was more about good practices, my code works, and I am now using the dispatch method.

Comment: I'm curious about the same thing, i.e. what best practices are. Instead of using a callback function passed to the action creator, I just passed "this.props.navigation" directly to the navigator and called it from there. Both solutions, passing this.props.navigation and passing a callback function work, but I'm curious what the recommended approach is and why.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, discussed [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/993), is to create a NavigationActions class that you can include in any non-component and thus use in your action creators to navigate. It sounds like a better solution is in development, but unclear when that will be published.